# Javascript Highcharts rename or remove series label in chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a Highchart column chart and at the bottom of the chart it says "Series 1"

That has been labelled automatically so I need to either rename that or just remove it.

Here is a screenshot showing exactly what I mean.

[image]

Comment: did you try this http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data: [{
    name: 'new name',
}
]
```

Read more details on official docs
http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the option, then remove:

```
legend: {
    enabled: false
}
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kofijita/3q9gL95u/2/